# Permanent Spike Line on a plotly plot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm wondering if it is possible in plotly to add a permanent spike line on a plot? The spike line should constantly sit at a particular value on the x-axis and read off and present the values from the y-axis and the right y-axis (even as the plot is being updated via dash).

I have been exploring the spike line options, but none seem to do the job.
fig.update_xaxes(showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='cursor', showline=True, spikedash='solid')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could try to mimick a spike line with a vertical line and an annotation.

You could do something like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4], "y": [1, 3, 5, 8]})
fig = px.line(df, x="x", y="y")

fig.add_vline(x=df.x.iloc[2], line_color="blue")
fig.update_traces(mode="lines+markers")
fig.add_annotation(
    x=df.x.iloc[2],
    y=df.y.iloc[2],
    xref="x",
    yref="y",
    xshift=30,
    text=f"x = {df.x.iloc[2]}<br>y = {df.y.iloc[2]}",
    showarrow=False,
    font=dict(family="Courier New, monospace", size=14, color="#ffffff"),
    align="center",
    bgcolor="blue",
)

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image: spike-line]

I've used a single vertical line here, because it resembles the spike line genereated by the code in your question, but you could also combine the vertical line with a horizontal line, make the line dotted, etc...

One thing you might not like with this approach is that if you have `hoverinfo` enabled the hoverinfo label will cover the annotation.